# Tkinter callbacks to main module

Tags: python, tkinter, model-view-controller

I've built a simple single-script GUI application in Tkinter which works as intended. Since the code for the Tk controls takes up half of the 600 lines script I'm trying to separate the GUI from the main application by putting it in a separate module.

In main.py file I have:

```
from mytkfile import MainWindow

def main():
    """Main program entry point."""
    decks = initialize()
    app = App(decks)
    app.view.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In mytkfile.py there is just a huge MainWindow class, which is currently is handling the callbacks to the different interface elements:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        # ...
```

The App class in main.py, simplified, looks like this:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, decks):
        self.decks = decks

        # ...

        self.view = MainWindow(self.deck)
        self.updateview()

    def updateview(self):
        # call several self.view.update_methods
```

The main window is drawn and basically works as it used to, because MainWindow handles a lot of the data logic itself. However, I would like to change that and have App handle everything and just ask MainWindow to update itself. I am trying to achieve this without App passing itself to MainWindow when instantiating it, because as I understand it a View should not know about its Controller, and should not be calling its own methods to handle data logic.

Problem is, how can I handle e.g. button callbacks in Tk when MainWindow doesn't know anything about App?

Comment: You state: `MainWindow doesn't know anything about App`, except your code contradicts you, because you have: `class MainWindow:` and `def __init__(self, app, deck):` where `app` seems to refer to `class App`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that "currently" the App object is passed to MainWindow because I can't figure out how to do it otherwise. Currently MainWindow doesn't do anything with the App object. I'll clarify the wording a bit.

Comment: You could apply the MVC (model-view-controller), and observer/event listener design patterns. The "model" is the actual data that's being manipulated, the "view" is your windows, buttons and widgets, and the "controller" is a thing that defines which operations are available to the user. When you press a button in the view, it fires an event which the controller is observing/listening for, and it triggers the corresponding callback/operation in the controller, which manipulates the model.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. But how can the App class "observe" e.g. a click in MainWindow? When I bind a callback function to a button click in Tkinter, MainWindow needs to know about that function. And how can that class know about that function if I'm not passing App to MainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [various](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/python/example) [articles](https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/tutorial-the-observer-pattern-in-python-879) on the observer design pattern in Python I've concluded that it's indeed impossible to at least slightly couple the Tkinter view MainWindow class to the model/controller App class in my code. It had been solved by the App class passing itself to the MainWindow, with Tk buttons notifying clicks to callback functions inside App. Works like a charm.